# What did Col. Hans Landa mean at the beginning of Inglorious Basterds

Tags: inglourious-basterds, quentin-tarantino

In the beginning of Inglorious Bastards, Col. Hans Landa asks the milk farmer if his "lovely daughters" could go out where his men were. The way he said it got me wondering if he was insinuating his men were going to use the girls for ill. Did anyone else wonder this or is it just me?

Comment: Can you add the time around which this happened or the dialogue in particular..?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He was not at all insinuating anything - he was merely asking to have a private conversation with the farmer.  What he says is:

```
COL LANDA:
Monsieur LaPadite, what we have to discuss
would be better discussed in
private. You'll notice, I left my men
outdoors- if it wouldn't offend them,
could you ask your lovely ladies to step
outside.
```

He only mentions his men to point out that they are able to have a private conversation without them.  He wants the farmer to reciprocate.  He doesn't say they need to go to the men, he asks them to step outside.

The farm-house is tiny, perhaps even one downstairs room.  There is nowhere else the women can go and not overhear the conversation.

Col. Landa probably wants to do this so he can concentrate on manipulating the farmer, who will be more inclined to be cooperative if the conversation is private.  The farmer knows there is a serious threat to the safety of his family from the Nazis, and the presence of the soldiers is definitely part of that - but I do not think he was specifically insinuating anything with this sentence.

Comment: Not to mention protecting the daughters. They don’t hear anything, thus they don’t know anything. This making them worthless for information should the Nazis get their hands on them. Ensures only the two men in the house are privy to what Landa had to say.

Comment: Not sure I agree with that.  Col Landa doesn't care about the daughters.  I presume also that the daughters *know* about the family hiding under the floor already.

Answer (score 1):

Having seen the film a dozen times, and having read the whole script, I would say that Quentin Tarantino, the writer director, wants you to have a certain amount of respect for Hans Landa, up until that point that he no longer wants you to have that respect for him.  That point being when he murders Bridget Von Hammersmark, an act that we need to see, so that we are no sympathetic to him when Aldo has a Swastika carved into his forehead.

But in the beginning we need to respect him and his professionalism, something that he harps on later in the film, so as such, he has the women leave, so as not to make it seem like they are pawns, nor subjected to witnessing the murder of the Jewish family, that he knows darn well are hiding there.

If those girls were present for any of this, we would not like him nearly as much going forward, and Quentin definitely wants us to like him for a while.

Quentin does nothing for no reason.  Everything has to make sense and have purpose.  Them leaving so that we the audience only had to concentrate on two characters instead of five, simply made sense.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis. In one way, you could respect his professionalism but on the other hand, you could despise it. I'm reminded of Inspector Javert out of Les Misérables. His professionalism is almost to a degree where one might think he worships the state and his worship of the state, takes all discernment out of him and he becomes a mere machine operating with the program that he was set with-a character it is easy to despise. Personally, that type of character quality makes me hate them all the more. ¯_(ツ)_/¯